# how to find the current position of a sprite in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am moving an object from one axis to another and when I touch it is stop on that Position , but how can I find its current position, when the user touches it will stop in that location and when the user double touch it, then it will move in another direction , I want to find out the current position of the object when I stop at that position when the user touches ..

Any idea.. about that.

---

thnx for the reply Arsalan, but my problem is that I have 3 sprite..

sprite.positoin.. , sprite1. position....., sprite2.position......, and in my game logic I do this thing. that

[sprite addChild:sprite1];
[sprite addChild:sprite2]; 
ok

and I have insert an action in the sprite. but when the user touches it will stop animating and I have to note down the final positon of sprite and also the sprite1 position. (remember that sprite1 is the subchild of sprite.)

how can I find out the sprite1.position.x value

any solution?

Comment: Hmm... CGPoint = sprite.position ?

Answer (score 0):

Well to get the position of a CCSprite any time in the game you can use the following code

```
mySprite.position;
```

To determine if you have touched the sprite you need to first get the Rect of sprite

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(mySprite.position.x-(mySprite.contentSize.width/2), mySprite.position.y-(mySprite.contentSize.height/2),
                         mySprite.contentSize.width, mySprite.contentSize.height;
```

then you have to check if the touch location is within the sprite rect or not.

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, touchLocation)) {
    // code to stop the movement of sprite
}
```

By the above code you can have an idea to proceed in which direction. You can also look into [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) for points and rects.

regards,

Arslan

Comment: Aslam o alkum, Arslan, I posted my exact question upwaard,. but see this and give me any suggestion..

Comment: thnx for the reply Arsalan, but my problem is that I have 3 sprite..

sprite.positoin.. , sprite1. position....., sprite2.position......, and in my game logic I do this thing. that

[sprite addChild:sprite1]; [sprite addChild:sprite2]; ok

and I have insert an action in the sprite. but when the user touches it will stop animating and I have to note down the final positon of sprite and also the sprite1 position. (remember that sprite1 is the subchild of sprite.)

how can I find out the sprite1.position.x value

any solution?